# How can i Pass variable into a sql file while running through python

Tags: python, sql

I have a Python wrapper which reads an SQL file and executes it.
Example:

```
query=job.get_sql_from_file("$DIR/file_path/file_name.sql")
job.execute(query)
job.query_desc()
```

$DIR : is default path declared in bashrc file

FILE_NAME.sql : contains schema name and path to read the input_file to load table:
I want that path to be dynamic and pass it as parameter.
How can i do that?

What I am aware of is:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (var1, var2, var3))
```

...but it will not work in my case because my SQL statement is in a .sql file and I have to pass argument in that file ITSELF.

Comment: can you show me what ur sql file look line and what you have to pass to that file?

Answer (score 5):

What I can suggest is you can read the file and then **replace**.

Example:
my test.sql file

```
select * from xxxxxx
```

now replace 'xxxxxx' with your table

```
table = 'my_table'
sql_statement = open('test.sql').read().replace('xxxxxx', table)
```

you can also use **format**:

Example:
my test.sql file

```
select * from {}
```

now use format

```
sql_statement = open('test.sql').read().format('my_table')
```

Comment: BUt my sql file is in path:..
Can i give like this:
query=job.get_sql_from_file("$DIR/file_path/open('file_name.sql').read().replace('xxxxxx',table)")

Comment: How about passing datetime parameters instead of table names? If use .replace('xxxxx', param), how can I replace many parameters?

Comment: I find the format method of string more flexible for combining for example env name in the schema name. Edited to highlight the 2 alternatives in the answer as I missed format

Answer (score 4):

Given a SQL file

`mysql_path.sql`

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '$name' AND age = $age;
```

From python you can do:

```
from string import Template

sql_path = 'dir/mysql_path.sql'

with open(sql_path, 'r') as fp:
    sql = fp.read()

query = Template(sql).substitute(
    name = 'Charles Darwin',
    age = 73,
)
```

That will give you:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'Charles Darwin' AND age = 73;
```

Comment: Nice. I've never heard of the Template class before so thanks for this smart solution.